# Save bitmap from selected file as new file into my own app folder

Tags: android

I just want to know on how can I save the image I selected from the gallery into my own folder as well as rename it but all the properties should remain in tact. Well I already have this method which came from a tutorial from vogella where you can select from gallery and display it as a preview. But instead of preview I just wanted do the thing I mentioned above. Here's the code:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    /*this method is used for getting and selecting image from gallery and display it in the imageView*/
    InputStream stream = null;
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
        try {
            if (bitmap != null) {
                bitmap.recycle();
            }
            stream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);

            preview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            //instead setting it in preview, save it in your image folder and rename it
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Well I do know some parts about saving a file but I'm really lost with this one so hope someone can help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private String saveToInternalSorage(Bitmap bitmapImage){
        ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
        File directory = cw.getDir("directoryName", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        File mypath=new File(directory,"profile.jpg");

        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try {
           // fos = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

            fos = new FileOutputStream(mypath);

            // Use the compress method on the BitMap object to write image to the OutputStream
            bitmapImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
            fos.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return directory.getAbsolutePath();
    }
```

Comment: hi, just some question. since I'm using a the method I posted above I wonder how can I get this part File directory = cw.getDir("directoryName", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

I'm lost with the directoryName part. Sorry I'm a bit slow on this.

Comment: You can give user defined name here. It basically creates a dir inside your application folder. For Ex: /data/data/com.your.app/app_data/"directoryName".. Am i clear ??

Answer (score 1):

Do this

```
public String writeFileToInternalStorage(Context context, Bitmap outputImage) {
   String fileName = Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".png";

   final FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
   outputImage.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 90, fos);
}
```

Comment: Ok some few questions here. 1. when should I use this method? should I use this after I decode the stream then pass the BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream) on this? calling it as writeFileToInternalStorage(getBaseContext(), bitmap);

and 2nd. what does the compressFormat.PNG do? Well I'm a bit curious since I prefered to save my image in JPG format.

Comment: yes, use it once you decode the stream. That is after this 


bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);

Comment: I'm having a Unhandled exception: java.io.FileNotFoundException on part of openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

Anyway since I wanted to save it in jpg format is it safe to change the filename into Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()/folder/folder/photo_name.jpg?

Comment: yea you could change it. and use CompressFormat.JPEG

Comment: I see, thanks for the advice, anyway I choose the answer above as the correct one since you both have the same output and although your code is shorter (which is I really preferred) but his answer is more safe and clear. Thanks for the help anyways so I give you a voteup. :)